Laravel 8 Unparenthesized `a ? b : c ?: d` is deprecated
I'm getting an error in Laravel backend
The line that is giving error:
<?php echo Form::select('percent', \VanguardLTE\Shop::$values['percent_labels'], $edit ? $shop->percent : old('percent')?:'90', ['class' => 'form-control']); ?>
error message:
Unparenthesized a ? b : c ?: dis deprecated. Use either(a ? b : c) ?: dora ? b : (c ?: d) (View: /home/lalala/public_html/resources/views/backend/shops/partials/base.blade.php) (View: /home/lalala/public_html/resources/views/backend/shops/partials/base.blade.php)

Use either (a ? b : c) ?: d or a ? b : (c ?: d)

Your error message clear says what to do error message: Unparenthesized a ? b : c ?: dis deprecated. Use either(a ? b : c) ?: dora ? b : (c ?: d)

It's not a Laravel issue. Nested ternary expressions are deprecated since PHP 7.4
Fix:
Form::select(
    'percent',
    \VanguardLTE\Shop::$values['percent_labels'],
    $edit ? $shop->percent : (old('percent') ?: '90'),
    ['class' => 'form-control']
);

This is probably what you wanted, though:
// If in edit mode, use $shop->percent,
// otherwise show old submitted value,
// or '90' if the user hasn't submitted yet
Form::select(
    'percent',
    \VanguardLTE\Shop::$values['percent_labels'],
    $edit ? $shop->percent : old('percent', '90'),
    ['class' => 'form-control']
);

